# HttpGeoipModule $geoip_country_code is blank

Tags: nginx

In nginx.conf:

```
http { 
    geoip_country /etc/nginx/GeoIP.dat;
    ...
}
```

If I do:

```
server{
    ...
    location / {
        add_header X-Geo $geoip_country_code;                   
        add_header X-Geo3 $geoip_country_code3;
        add_header X-IP $remote_addr;
        ...
    }
}
```

Only `X-IP` show up in my headers.

```
$ curl -I www.example.org
HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 17 Jan 2013 19:29:23 GMT
Location: http://www.example.org/login/?next=/
Server: nginx/1.2.2
Vary: Cookie
X-IP: 10.139.34.12
Connection: keep-alive
```

If I change the location block to:

```
location / {
    add_header X-Geo "foo";                   
    add_header X-Geo3 "bar";
    add_header X-IP $remote_addr;
    ...
}
```

The headers show up, how can I get `$geoip_country_code`?

Comment: Please post your _other_ `location` blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found out the geo_ip has an internal option to use the `X-Forwarded-For`:

```
syntax: geoip_proxy address | CIDR;
default:     —
context:    http
This directive appeared in versions 1.3.0 and 1.2.1.
Defines trusted addresses. When a request comes from a trusted address, an address from the “X-Forwarded-For” request header field will be used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah I just figure out what was happening. It was trying to resolve the GeoIP for the LoadBalancers IP rather than the client which is why it was blank. Once I curled the host directly, it returned the correct result. I had to use the HttpRealipModule  to give the HttpGeoipModule the clients IP. In my conf:

```
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you confirm what headers are being sent when you access the / URL? Can you try this curl command?

Something similar to this but with your URL:

```
% curl -I www.google.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 17 Jan 2013 18:58:36 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=39403a60450f4bb3:FF=0:TM=1358449116:LM=1358449116:S=uoBAz3VFZpjyc1hA; expires=Sat, 17-Jan-2015 18:58:36 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Set-Cookie: NID=67=MBsS_mn5gvM2Zzt6Q6kfIO5h_brntWLnAmxZAXsNPseUgb5puv_8p8Io0ybgRqY62z0ihF-G5DLFtQOMN5MyIzM70IgPbkN4qOXKhCnQuUUqGCyuKkCg5XL6WfZoDR9m; expires=Fri, 19-Jul-2013 18:58:36 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: I've edited the question and included the curl response. I was confirming it with curl and chromes developer toolbar.

Comment: If you set the headers with static strings do they still not show up?

Comment: @sim They do, just tried it.

Comment: So is the issue something with those variable values getting set then?

Comment: Turns out the issue was that it was grabbing the IP of the LoadBalancer to do the matching, which didn't match anything and then left the variables blank which didn't push out the headers.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. That's kind of what I was poking at, that if those variables are blank there is nothing to set those variables to, so they're getting dropped. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Here's some points for the help anyways, since I answered my own question. :)

Comment: Thanks, just glad you figured it out, is' always rewarding to solve a technical problem!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can specify your IP source when configuring your **geoip** block. Note: I have only tested this on GeoIP2

```
geoip2 /etc/nginx/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb {
    $geoip2_data_country_code source=$http_x_forwarded_for country iso_code;
}
```